# Onerror running anyway even when no error

Tags: javascript, onerror

Ok So I'm trying to run some javascript whenever theres an issue loading an image provided by an ad network.

The ads are showing fine but my scripts are getting called anyway. Am i going about this the wrong way?

code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function catchAdLoadError(i) {
        console.log("error happened loading advert " + i);
        trackingInfo['adfailedtoload'] = 'testad' + i;

        document.getElementById("t-tracking-fragment").innerHTML = vsDoTracking();
    }
    $(function() {
        document.getElementById("advertBanner0").addEventListener("error", catchAdLoadError(0));
        document.getElementById("advertBanner1").addEventListener("error", catchAdLoadError(1));
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error function is being called and interpreted when you are setting the event listener. Use an anonymous function to define the event listener:

```
document.getElementById("advertBanner0").addEventListener("error", function(){ catchAdLoadError(0) } );
```

instead of :

```
document.getElementById("advertBanner0").addEventListener("error", catchAdLoadError(0));
```

the same for the second event listener.

**Notes:**

The function addEventListener expects parameters in this format:

```
addEventListener( eventName, callbackFunction )
```

When you specify some function to listen an event, the 2nd parameter expected is a **function object**, not a **function call**, so `catchAdLoadError(0)` executes immediately. You could put a function name directly like `catchAdLoadError` but since you need an exta parameter in the function call (0 or 1), you must put each specific call in an anonymous function that will be called by the event.

Comment: works perfect (although not sure why this is a necessity, if theres a link or something to read up on about why this type of thing is needed etc 'd be happy to hear it to read up and educate myself more on it!)

Comment: Great! I've edited the answer to put some additional notes about that